# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 at test.GameOfLife.main(gameOfLife.java:10)

Tags: java, arrays

Here is my code

```
class GameOfLife {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int height = 0;
    int width = 0;
    int [][][] universe = new int [2][20][20]; 
    for (height=0; height <= 5; height ++){
        for (width=0; width <= 5; width++){
            universe [2][height][width]= 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(universe[2][2][3]);
}
}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at test.GameOfLife.main(gameOfLife.java:10)

Comment: Are you using Eclipse IDE to help you debug your code? I highly recommend it.

Comment: Arrays index from ZERO and not ONE.

Answer (score 1):

When you define universe

```
int [][][] universe = new int [2][20][20];
```

It has two spots, index 0 and index 1. You should probably do

```
int depth;
for (depth=0; depth < universe.length; depth ++) {
  for (height=0; height < universe[depth].length; height ++){
    for (width=0; width < universe[depth][height].length; width++){
        universe [depth][height][width]= 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array `universe`:
The first index must be `0` or `1`.

When you define one array, the index start by zero:
[image]

**See also:**

[Java array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 1):

Maximum index of Array with size `2` is `1`

```
int [][][] universe = new int [2][20][20]
                               ^
```

thus, `System.out.print(universe[2][2][3]);` is throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access universe[2][][], you have to define this with

```
int [][][] universe = new int[3][20][20];
```

pointers start from '0'.